# How to get keyboard keys state on Mac OSX?

Tags: c#, macos, mono

Is there any way that I can get keyboard keys status (esp. for games) in Mac using only Mono C#?

I am looking for purely C# based solution, not any other API. Is there any support like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I found myself in the same situation and you either have to use the Control class under System.Windows.Forms, or follow the instructions of [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993633/how-to-get-keyboard-state-in-objective-c-without-referring-to-nsevent) and adapt it to the C# world

I was particularly interested in the caps key, so I did:

```
    [DllImport("/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/ApplicationServices")]
    public static extern long CGEventSourceFlagsState(int keyCode);
    bool CapsLock = (CGEventSourceFlagsState(1) & 0x00010000) != 0;
```

Hope this helps!