# How to get keyboard state in Objective-C without referring to NSEvent

Tags: objective-c, macos, keyboard

Is it possible to get the keyboard state in Objective-C without referring to `NSEvent`?

In general I can't use `NSResponder` methods like `-[NSResponder flagsChanged:]` but I need to know if the Command key is currently pressed.

Comment: Um. **Why** can't you refer to NSEvent?

Comment: The answer to this question from today should be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994656/how-to-tell-if-a-modifier-key-is-down-during-drop-on-dock

Comment: @Grady: `+[NSEvent modifierFlags]` does not use _an_ event, it uses the `NSEvent` class, which is available in any app that includes AppKit. (Why you would need to know what the keyboard is doing if you're not using AppKit is beyond me.) `GetCurrentKeyModifiers()` wouldn't know an event if it came up and bit it on the a** -- but it is Carbon, and, I concede, not the best solution. It would be helpful to answerers if shpoont elaborated on why `NSEvent` can't be used.

Comment: Sorry I misread, I was referring to [NSApp currentEvent]... your are right that the GetCurrentKeyModifiers() isn't an event, or awesome.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm still wondering why you can't use `NSEvent`, but I'm going to answer the question anyways. Perhaps you're building a "command-line tool" and are only linked against Foundation? You're going to have to include at least one more framework. If you want to link against AppKit, you can (as I mentioned in the comments) use [`+[NSEvent modifierFlags]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000016-SW22); this is a class method on `NSEvent`, so you can use it anywhere, without needing to have access to an individual event, to get the current state of the modifier keys as a bitmask. The docs explain the [meaning of the bitmask](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Modifier_Flags).

```
if( NSCommandKeyMask & [NSEvent modifierFlags] ){
    NSLog(@"Oh, yeah!");
}
```

You can also get this info using [Quartz Event Services](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html). In this case you have to include the ApplicationServices framework*. The [CGEventSource functions](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003550-CH202-318932) will give you the [same bitmask](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CGEventFlags) you get from `NSEvent`:

```
CGEventFlags theFlags;
theFlags = CGEventSourceFlagsState(kCGEventSourceStateHIDSystemState);
if( kCGEventFlagMaskCommand & theFlags ){
    NSLog(@"Uh huh!");
}
```

---

*This is already included if you are, in fact, writing a Cocoa app -- it's part of Quartz.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code when targeting macOS 10.12 or newer:

```
if (NSEventModifierFlagCommand & NSEvent.modifierFlags) {
    // Do whatever is needed
}
```