# How to tell if a modifier key is down during drop on Dock

Tags: cocoa, macos, drag-and-drop, keyboard, dock

My Cocoa application supports dropping files onto its Dock icon, but I'd like different behavior depending on whether a modifier key is held down (Command, Option, etc.).

I tried checking the `modifierFlags` for the `currentEvent`, but they are the same regardless of whether a modifier is held down, or not (I was testing with the Option key).

**Code:**

```
// Code is inside my AppDelegate
- (void)application:(NSApplication *)theApplication openFiles:(NSArray *)files {
    BOOL optDown = (([[NSApp currentEvent] modifierFlags] & NSAlternateKeyMask)
                    == NSAlternateKeyMask);
    NSLog(@"flags: %u, down? %@", [[NSApp currentEvent] modifierFlags],
          optDown ? @"YES" : @"NO");
}
```

**Output** (dropping a file with the Option key down, then not):

```
flags: 1088, down? NO
flags: 1088, down? NO
```

**Expected**

```
flags: <not sure>, down? YES
flags: <different>, down? NO
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In general, you can't expect `[NSApp currentEvent]` to have anything to do with the current user state if your app is not frontmost.

To get the hardware state, which will work regardless of the frontmost app, `GetCurrentKeyModifiers()` is supported back to 10.0 (including 64-bit); `[NSEvent modifierFlags]` is another option if you can require 10.6.

Comment: Thanks, `[NSEvent modifierFlags]`did the trick perfectly (I do require 10.6).