# How to get current modifier states with FireMonkey on OSX?

Tags: macos, delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey, keyevent

With **Delphi** for Windows, I usually use this code:

```
function isCtrlDown : Boolean;
var
  ksCurrent : TKeyboardState;
begin
  GetKeyboardState(ksCurrent);
  Result := ((ksCurrent[VK_CONTROL] and 128) <> 0);
end;
```

**How can I achieve this with FireMonkey on Mac OSX?**

I have found [this](http://opensource.apple.com/source/WebCore/WebCore-955.66/platform/mac/KeyEventMac.mm?txt), but I don't know how to manage it with FireMonkey/Delphi (which uses, ...):

```
void PlatformKeyboardEvent::getCurrentModifierState(bool& shiftKey, bool& ctrlKey, bool& altKey, bool& metaKey)
{
    UInt32 currentModifiers = GetCurrentKeyModifiers();
    shiftKey = currentModifiers & ::shiftKey;
    ctrlKey = currentModifiers & ::controlKey;
    altKey = currentModifiers & ::optionKey;
    metaKey = currentModifiers & ::cmdKey;
}
```

I'm still investigating...
For now, I have find this unit with **key events** stuff...
`unit Macapi.AppKit;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993633/how-to-get-keyboard-state-in-objective-c-without-referring-to-nsevent) you could try this:

```
function isCtrlDown : Boolean; 
begin
    Result := NSControlKeyMask and TNSEvent.OCClass.modifierFlags = NSControlKeyMask;
end;
```

Answer (score 6):

This returns the current shift state:

```
uses
  Macapi.CoreGraphics;

function KeyboardModifiers: TShiftState;
const
  kVK_Shift                     = $38;
  kVK_RightShift                = $3C;
  kVK_Control                   = $3B;
  kVK_Command                   = $37;
  kVK_Option                    = $3A;
begin
  result := [];
  if (CGEventSourceKeyState(0, kVK_Shift) <> 0) or (CGEventSourceKeyState(0, kVK_RightShift) <> 0) then Include(result, ssShift);
  if CGEventSourceKeyState(0, kVK_Command) <> 0 then Include(result, ssCommand);
  if CGEventSourceKeyState(0, kVK_Option) <> 0 then Include(result, ssAlt);
  if CGEventSourceKeyState(0, kVK_Control) <> 0 then Include(result, ssCtrl);
end;
```

Comment: Both solutions posted during my sleep are working. Sorry, I have accepted the other one because it was posted some few minutes earlier... it has been hard to choose between both of you. BTW, you get a +1

Comment: In Delphi 11 the function returns a boolean so the new code would look like


if CGEventSourceKeyState(0, kVK_Command) then Include(result, ssCommand);