# Get KeyStrokes for OSX in RAD Studio XE2 delphi?

Tags: macos, delphi, delphi-xe2, keylogger

I want to make a Fire Monkey app in RAD studio xe2 that will save keystrokes for OSX.I have read about CGEvent or Apple Script for such development.Is it possible in RAD Studio XE2?please guide...

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876911/how-to-get-current-modifier-states-with-firemonkey-on-osx or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13492531/getkeystate-in-firemonkey